# WP All Export for Wordpress: How to use if, elseif condition to get and change attribute data

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, function, wpallimport

Is there method to use wp all export php functions to replace data or maybe any other statement we can use directly inside custom XML export.

What i need is to achieve this logic

I have custom taxonomy in XML called {Conditions} which return value of each post as "Used" "New"

Values appear correctly, but where i need to export XML required different values then those above, which i need to replace during export.

```
Logic:
If {Conditions} = "Used"
Set Used = "20";
Elseif{Conditions} = "New"
Set New = "10";
```

[WP ALL EXPORT PLUGIN](https://www.wpallimport.com/documentation/developers/custom-code/if-statements/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at "Pass Data Through PHP Functions" doc:

*"...you can click on the export field and then use the "Export the value returned by a PHP function" option."*

https://www.wpallimport.com/documentation/export/pass-data-through-php-functions/

You would specify the function name into the text field as in the screenshot on the documentation page (`convert_conditions`) or, if running a custom XML export, call the function from the field with something like this:

`[convert_conditions({Conditions})]`

...and provide the function in the function editor for the field:

```
function convert_conditions($cond_from_xml = null) {
    if($cond_from_xml === 'Used') {
        return '20';
    } elseif($cond_from_xml === 'New') {
        return '10';
    } else {
        return '0';
    }
}
```